# Scraping meta tags with BS4 or Newspaper3k in Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, meta-tags

After an exhaustive search and many variations, I am at a loss. I know that BS4 (I also tried 3) is supposed to be able to scrape meta tags, but I cannot seem to get it to work. The meta-tags in question are closed `<properly />` so that isn't it. They always exist (even though I set up a catch in case), so that is not it. I have tried loops, I have tried different formats for the same thing. I have even tried Newspaper and Newspaper3k. Finally, I have tried the lxml, html5lib, and html.parser libraries, all to no avail.

Any advice would help... please.

My HTML source looks like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="Here is an exclusive we just got in regarding toda...." />
<meta property="og:description" content="Here is an exclusive we just got in regarding toda...." />
<meta property="article:section" content="Breaking News" />
```

and my python code looks like this:

```
# Import requisite libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Start it up (and note I have also tried lxml and html.parser)
soup = BeautifulSoup(corpus, 'html5lib')
# corpus is holding data from Newspaper3k. This aspect works.


# Following is just me trying different ways to find the same 2 things:

# Retrieve description AKA summary
description = soup.find("meta",  property="og:description")  # 1st way
summary = soup.find("meta",  attrs={'name': "description"})  # 2nd way

# Retrieve category AKA section
category = soup.find("meta",  property='article:section')  # 1st way
section = soup.find("meta",  attrs={'article': "section"})  # 2nd way


# Test and return result
print(description["content"] if description else "No description given")
print(summary["content"] if summary else "No summary given")
print(category["content"] if category else "No category given")
print(section["content"] if section else "No section given")
```

- It always returns:

  ```
  No description given
  No summary given
  No category given
  No section given
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Okay... I solved it. The problem was that I was using the corpus I pulled from Newspaper3k as the data-set. Don't get me wrong... this works as it says on the label... but the meta-tags won't be in there as it only pulls in the article body and authors.

However, when I instead use BS4 to now pull the data, it actually pulls in the underlying data as well (and not just the article body) which means it now has the meta-tags.

We can close this, thank you for your patience.

The proper code would look like this:

```
    url = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.someurl.com/breakingnews/this-just-in/')
    content = url.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

    description = soup.find("meta",  property="og:description")
    summary = soup.find("meta",  attrs={'name': "description"})
    category = soup.find("meta",  property='article:section')

    print(description["content"] if description else "No description given")
    print(summary["content"] if summary else "No summary given")
    print(category["content"] if category else "No category given")
```

and then the rest as before.